# Poor Write Speeds with Specific Brand of Hard Drive

Tags: server, hard-drive

I've been scratching my head all week trying to figure this out.

A little preamble, this is a custom built server using a Supermicro X8SIL motherboard with a Xeon x3470, running Ubuntu Server 18.04. I've got an SSD and several WD drives running on both the onboard SATA ports and a PCIe SATA card with no issues. All has been behaving normal up until this week.

I recently acquired several 1TB 5400rpm HGST drives in the hopes of setting up a few RAID 1 arrays. I noticed that the arrays were resyncing extremely slow (at around 10MB/s at best) so I did some investigating. I formatted the drives individually as ext4 filesystems and ran some speed tests with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/xyz bs=100k count=100 oflag=direct`

What I'm seeing is a very bizarre issue. These new drives exhibit very poor write speeds when connected to the system using a known good SATA cable (verified with a known good drive to get expected write speeds). It doesn't matter whether or not it's the SATA ports on the motherboard or the PCIe card, the max write speeds I can get out of these drives is about 7-9MB/s depending on which drive I use.

However, additional testing with a USB->SATA adapter plugged into a USB2 port on the server yields way better speeds, upwards of 30MB/s, without changing anything else about the partitions or filesystems on these drives. That's the same speed a known good drive gives on the adapter (it is USB2 after all), so I'm led to believe that there's not something fundamentally wrong with the new HGST drives and that it's a specific interaction between SATA operation on the motherboard and the specific firmware/controller/whatever on these drives. SMART data appears normal with no errors as far as I can see.

I've tested four separate HGST drives (2 p/n 0J38083 and 2 p/n 0J37013) and verified that all four exhibit the exact same behavior discussed above. SATA is a no-go, but USB->SATA seems to work normally. I've also taken several random drives from other manufacturers and run the same tests on the same hardware and write speeds remain the same across all tests.

I can't for the life of me imagine what would be causing an issue like that and I don't know where I'd even begin troubleshooting. Recommendations on more troubleshooting ideas or different settings to change would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: In response to a comment, here is the output of `uname -a` and `arch`

```
$ uname -a
Linux axel-base 4.15.0-60-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 16:55:30 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ arch
x86_64
```

Comment: Are you using 32-bit kernel with PAE? Please add output of `uname -a` (kernel version) and `arch` (CPU architecture) to the question.

Comment: Updated with info